# How resize TortoiseGit commit message text box?

Tags: tortoisegit

I've somehow managed to make my TortoiseGit commit dialog commit message text box to be one line long.

[image]

However I cannot find a setting that would reset it. I've have uninstalled and removed TortoiseGit and installed the latest versions. But it's still returns.

Oh and resizing the dialog doesn't fix it.

Comment: Why the close vote? This question is about a coding tool - absolutely within the Stack overflow remit.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Move mouse to the position between **Message** and **Changes made (double-click on file for diff)** group box (see following figure)

[image]

Then drag down to the position where you want.

And it's bigger:

[image]

Comment: Mine was not showing at all after I had changed the display resolution a number of time. It was showing up as just one line. This helped! Thank you!